# Python not able to save some CLOB xml into xml file

Tags: python, xml, oracle

I have this xml saved as CLOB in my oracle database:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DCResponse>
...
</DCResponse>
```

and with this python code I am able to save content into xml file:

```
sql = "select extract(xmltype.createxml(xml), '//DCResponse').getStringVal() from table t where id = 2"
for row in cursor.execute(sql):
    print(row[0])
with open("output.xml", "w") as f:
    f.write(row[0])
```

Instead with this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<PIPEDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:XML-PIPE 
PIPEDocument.xsd" ReferenceNumber="567862650" CreationDate="20200115155255" Version="1.0"  
xmlns="urn:XML-PIPE">
...
</PIPEDocument>
```

I'm not able to extract the content with python. Write() argument must be str, not None.....is result in Python console running this code:

```
sql = "select extract(xmltype.createxml(xml), '//PIPEDocument').getStringVal() from table t where id 
= 7"
for row in cursor.execute(sql):
    print(row[0])
with open("output.xml", "w") as f:
    f.write(row[0])
```

In my oracle client the output of the below sql query, used in python, is null:

```
select extract(xmltype.createxml(xml), '//PIPEDocument').getStringVal() from table t where id = 7;
```

while the xml content is present in my DB:

```
select xml from table where id =7
```

Not sure what is the issue, maybe the keyword '//PIPEDocument' in the select query or different encoding between the 2 XML files, but no idea how to fix this.

Please Help
Best Regards
Giancarlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your second XML document you have namespaces.  The element `<PIPEDocument>` is in the namespace `xmlns="urn:XML-PIPE"`, and your XPath expression `//PIPEDocument'` only matches elements `<PIPEDocument>` in the 'default' namespace.

If you want to use namespaces with the `extract` function you have to add:

- a namespace mapping of a prefix to the namespace URI, using the optional third argument to `extract`.  This third argument is a string formatted in the same way as `xmlns:*` attributes in XML documents.  You can't map the default namespace in this way, so `xmlns="urn:XML-PIPE"` won't work here.  Instead, use a prefix, such as `p`, or perhaps `pipe`.
- add the prefix to the XPath expression in the second argument to `extract`.

I made these changes to your code, choosing to use the namespace prefix `p`.  I also wrapped the entire SQL string in triple-quotes to avoid me having to escape the quotes inside it.  This gave me the following, which returned the desired XML output:

```
sql = """select extract(xmltype.createxml(xml), '//p:PIPEDocument', 'xmlns:p="urn:XML-PIPE"').getStringVal() from table t where id = 7"""
for row in cursor.execute(sql):
    print(row[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

For query performance, you might want to fetch the LOB as a String, see the [doc](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/lob_data.html#fetching-lobs-as-strings-and-bytes).

For general reference, if the database type had been XMLType,  [cx_Oracle's recommendation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/xml_data_type.html) is to use `xmltype.getclobval()` to avoid limited XML lengths.

Update: The latest version of cx_Oracle, [now called python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a) has a Thin mode that doesn't have the [XML query length limitation](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/release_notes.html#oracledb-1-2-0-november-2022).

Comment: Excellent recommendation, thank you!